# how to add one string arraylist values into another integer arraylist with out duplicates in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am coping one String arraylist values another integer arraylist, i want copy with out duplicates i tried using below code but its not copying all values...where  did mistake suggest me...

ShootAndCropActivity.class:

```
public class ShootAndCropActivity extends Activity  {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
static Vector<Integer> genrated4=new Vector<Integer>();
static ArrayList<String> genratednew=new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> multimeaning=new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    multimeaning.add("radha");
    multimeaning.add("swathi");
    multimeaning.add("sudha");
    multimeaning.add("sai");
    multimeaning.add("jyothi");
    multimeaning.add("radha");

    Random random4 = new Random();        
    for (int i4 = 0; i4<multimeaning.size(); i4++){ 
        int randomNumber4 = random4.nextInt(multimeaning.size());
        String mn1=String.valueOf(multimeaning.get(randomNumber4));

        if(!genratednew.contains(mn1)) {
            genratednew.add(mn1);
            genrated4.add(randomNumber4);
        }
     }
 }
 }
```

In above multimeaning arraylist, I have 6 names. In the list one value "radha" is there 2  times. So I want to add all those multimeaning arraylist elements into another integer arraylist. But its not copying all those values,I dont hasset,because I want follow order I want order...

Comment: if you want to maintain order then why are you using `Random` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want everything in order and just want to skip the duplicate values then don't use `Random`.

Just replace the following code

```
Random random4 = new Random();        
for (int i4 = 0; i4<multimeaning.size(); i4++){ 
    int randomNumber4 = random4.nextInt(multimeaning.size());
    String mn1=String.valueOf(multimeaning.get(randomNumber4));

    if(!genratednew.contains(mn1)) {
        genratednew.add(mn1);
        genrated4.add(randomNumber4);
    }
 }
```

with

```
for (int i4 = 0; i4<multimeaning.size(); i4++){ 
    String mn1=String.valueOf(multimeaning.get(i4));

    if(!genratednew.contains(mn1)) {
        genratednew.add(mn1);
        genrated4.add(i4);
    }
 }
```

I hope it will be helpful !

Comment: ok, i want random action also,i just dont want change arralist first postion value,remain all postion  i need to select random way

Comment: becz i am doing quiz game here i know ans already so i am adding those answer in first postion of arraylist,reamin all options i need to display random answers every time

Comment: your right.i just shuffled multimening array after addin answer  to genratednew array and every time copying.now its working

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set. A set is unique collection of items. Does not have duplicates. You can use the below to remove duplicates in a arraylist. Then copy accordingly.

```
static ArrayList<String> multimeaning=new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> hs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
// maintains insertion order and will have unique collection of items
hs.addAll(multimeaning);
multimeaning.clear();
multimeaning.addAll(hs);
```

Comment: thankou.if we add data into hasset means that time elements order will change right?but i want same order

Comment: @radha same order in the sense which order? if i understood correctly it is randomly generated order

Comment: @radha use a linkedhashset maintains insertion order.

Comment: means in my case in multimeaning arralist what ever the order i added elements same order i want in genrated4 arralist  also,like[radha,swathi,sudha----]

Comment: @radha use linkedhashset it maintains the insertion order and uniqueness